# pyserial 2.7 and USB Relay module

Tags: python, pyserial

I've purchased two lctech-inc.com 011801 USB Relay Modules. I'm trying to control them with python and pyserial. The module does show up as USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM5). The support information says:

```
Communication baud rate: 9600bps; Protocol: start: 0 x A0, 
switch address: 0 x 01, operation data: 0 x 00 (off), 0 x 01 (on), 
check code: on: A0 01 01 A2, off: A0 01 00 A1
```

I'm using the following python code to turn the relay on but it doesn't work:

```
    import sys
    import serial
    portName = "COM5"
    relayNum = "1"
    relayCmd = "on"
    #Open port for communication    
    serPort = serial.Serial(portName, 9600, timeout=1)
    #Send the command
    serPort.write("relay "+ str(relayCmd) +" "+ str(relayNum) + "\n\r")
    print "Command sent..."
    #Close the port
    serPort.close()
```

As long as I use the correct COM port, COM5, I do not get any errors.

Any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

I needed to encode as HEX. Here is what worked.

```
import serial
port = 'COM3'
ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600, timeout=1)
# To close relay (ON)
code = 'A00101A2'
ser.write(code.decode('HEX'))
ser.close()
# To open relay (OFF)
code = 'A00100A1'
ser.write(code.decode('HEX'))
ser.close()
```

Comment: For Python 3.6.0: serPort.write(codecs.decode(b'A00101A2','hex'))

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to send the byte 0x01 to turn the relay on and 0x00 to turn it off, not strings "on" and "off".

Try `serPort.write(0x01)` to turn the relay on.

Edit: It also looks like you might need to send the start byte 0xA0 first.

Comment: I tried serPort.write("0xA0 0x01") with no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Don't use quotes. Also try sending just 0xA0 then 0x01 with a second call to write

Comment: I did try both and still no luck.